# ASP.NET validation summary doesn't show validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a new validator added to one screen to validate a text box. If user clicks on submit button, the validation summary will pop up but not showing the text of this validator. It works well with all other validators on this page.

In other words, this validator works but is not shown in the validation summary.

Comment: Post some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Are you using ValidationGroup Property with the validators?

Comment: I figured it out, I used the Text property of the validator instead of ErrorMessage property. Thanks for your comment @MichaelLiu

Comment: You ought to answer this yourself and mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use the same name as the default validation group may not verification. I suggest you to check out her hard have added value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used the Text property of the validator instead of ErrorMessage property. Thanks for your comment @MichaelLiu which made me look at the code.